# skipping over IndexError in for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, indexing

How can I skip over the error "IndexError: list index out of range" and proceed with the remaining for loop?  For example I have:

```
from bisect import bisect

thelist = [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
thevalues = [.1, .2, .3, .6, .7, .8, .9]

my_items = [10, 1, 9, 4, 3]

found_list = []
found_values = []

for i in my_items:
    position = bisect(thelist, i)
    found_list.append(thelist[position])
    found_values.append(thevalues[position])
```

desired output:

```
found_list = [1, 9, 3]
found_values = [.1, .9, .3]
```

But since 10 is not in 'thelist' I get an error first time through the loop.  Even if there are values in 'my_items' that aren't in 'thelist', can I skip over these (in a time efficient way and without having to change my_list) and just get the found values?

Comment: Have you considered [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for valid indexes:

```
for i in my_items:
  position = bisect(thelist, i)
  if position < len(thelist):
    found_list.append(thelist[position])
    found_values.append(thevalues[position])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `try-except` here. It's a way to manage control-flow that allows you to attempt to perform an action that might throw an error (such as `IndexError`) and do some cleanup. It would look like this:

```
for i in my_items:
    try:
        position = bisect(thelist, i)
        found_list.append(thelist[position])
        found_values.append(thevalues[position])
    except IndexError:
        print('{0} is not in thelist'.format(position))
```

As a side-benefit, this is actually very Pythonic. If you're interested in learning more about using `try-except` to manage control-flow, check out [this blog-post](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/).